# I need help writing a formula that concatenates fields (and adds text) but displays blank if all fields are blank

Tags: list, column

First, I have very minimal formula writing skills (I'm trying to learn). I was able to create a SharePoint list and have a calculated column titled [Shipment Date Summary] with the following formula:

```
="On ”&[Date Shipment Changed]&" Shipment date changed from ”&[Prior Shipment Date]&" to ”&[New Shipment Date]
```

1. This formula works.  However, if the columns are blank, my formatted text displays.  How do I write a formula that returns a blank IF the fields I want to concatenate are blank ELSE maintain the formula operating as it currently is?
2. Furthermore, I will create a [Date Summary] column which will consolidate the [Shipment Date Summary] data (from formula above) as well as 2 other calculated formulas for [Order Date Summary] and [Arrival Date Summary].

Answer (score 0):

To check for blank you can use the ISBLANK or LEN function

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805008/if-function-sharepoint-not-empty-column)

I did not get your second question.

Comment: Thank you, Manu. Amal responded with a formula. About the second question, I need to create an overall [Date Summary] calculated column that consolidates data from various calculated columns (but yet, leaves this new column blank if no data is in any column)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the BLANK check using

```
IF(ISBLANK([FieldName], "empty", "not empty"))
```

So your final formula will be come something like

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Shipment Changed]),"",IF(ISBLANK([Prior Shipment Date]),"",IF(ISBLANK([New Shipment Date]),"","On "&[Date Shipment Changed]&" Shipment date changed from "&[Prior Shipment Date]&" to "&[New Shipment Date])))
```

You can use the same approach for `[Date Summary]` field.

Comment: Thank you, Amal. I tried using that formula and it did not work???  I get message "formula contains syntax error or is not supported". I checked the formula you wrote and edited the spacing to see if that was issue, but i could not get it to work?  I am pretty new at this.

Comment: @Pspet please try updated answer.

Comment: Amal, I have copied your revised formula and retyped it and it is still not working. Any other leads?

Comment: @Pspet i forgot to place `IF` statements. Please try updated formula. You can copy paste instead of typing.

Comment: Amal, that worked!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  I will create my other 2 calculated fields [Order Date Summary] and [Arrival Date Summary] using the same premise.  Then I will create the formula for the [Date Summary].  I truly appreciate your help.  Hope you don't mind if I write back if I get stuck.  You are awesome!!!

Comment: Amal, I just ran a test and checked my data.  The formula works.  However, I realized I did not consider a scenerio where the New Shipment date changed from a vallue to blank (in that we changed the shipment date to blank b/c we are waiting to hear about a new date).  How do I edit that piece so that I see if new date is supposed to be blank?

Comment: It is also feasible for the [Prior Shipment Date] and [New Shipment Date] to be updated from having a value to blank.  These results are not displaying with formula you provided. Sorry, I did not think of these scenarios.  Any additional help is appreciated.